# Get Document in Firestore Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a Firebase cloud function that messages a particular user when their rating has been updated (a trigger from Firestore).

So far I have;

```
// Send New Rating Notifications
exports.sendNewRatingNotification = functions.firestore.document('users/{userID}/ratings/{ratingID}').onWrite((context) => {

    // Get {userID} and field of fcmToken and set as below

    var fcmToken = fcmToken;
    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "You have recieved a new rating",
            body: "Your rating is now..."
        }
    }

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, payload).then(function(response) {
        console.log('Sent Message', response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error Message", error);
    })
})
```

I need to access the `{userID}` documents' fcmToken field to use below how to I approach this from using the wildcard `{userID}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is spelled out in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters) for wildcards:

```
exports.sendNewRatingNotification =
functions.firestore.document('users/{userID}/ratings/{ratingID}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const userID = context.params.userID
})
```

Note that the first argument to the callback is not `context`, it's Change object that describes the before and after state of the document.  The second argument is a context that contains the parameters of the change.

Comment: thanks, @Doug can I access the fcmToken field directly (const fcmToken = context.param.fcmToken) or do I need to get the document data of the user then access the fcmToken field.

Comment: There is no token field in the context.  You'll have to store and retrieve that per user.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented the process from the accepted answer above.

My Firebase Function is as follows;

```
exports.sendNewRatingNotification = functions.firestore.document('users/{userID}/ratings/{ratingID}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    var userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.params.userID);
    return userRef.get().then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
            console.log('No such document!');
        } else {
            const data = change.after.data();
            const fcmToken = doc.data().fcmToken;
            var payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: "New Rating",
                    body: "You have recieved a " + data["rating"] + "* rating"
                }
            }
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, payload).then(function(response) {
                console.log('Sent Message:', response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error Message:', error);
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check line number [30-31](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L30-L31) of [functions-samples/fcm-notifications](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/) repository.

You will get using:

```
  const userID= context.params.userID;
```

Hope it will helps you.

Thank you.